# Difference in confidence intervals of two sample sizes given a finite population

Tags: sample-size, confidence-interval

I can't seem to wrap my head around this problem. My company is commissioning a facility that recovers two types of metal from ash generated from an incinerator: ferrous (metal containing iron) and non-ferrous (metals that don't contain iron; e.g. aluminum).

In our commissioning test, the total population of an ash batch we have to sample from is 200 tons, which contains 4% ferrous, 1% non-ferrous, and 95% ash.
Our facility that we built is designed to recover 90% of all ferrous matter, and 85% of all non-ferrous matter.

We proposed a test where take out 20 tons (10% of total pop.) randomly, then analyze the composition before it goes into our facility, then after.

One of my higher up managers think that 20 tons isn't enough, so he proposed we do 60 tons. We have only two days to perform the test and it takes us 12 hours to do a 20 ton test; no way in hell will we even consider 60 tons.

I want to know the difference in confidence intervals of the 20 ton sample, and a 60 ton sample using a 95% confidence level.

How should I approach to solve this problem? I appreciate any help you guys can provide me.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of unanswered questions here, but as a rule of thumb, the sampling error scales by the *square root* of your sample size. Now, you seem to have a continuous sample (tons vs people or tests), so as a first approximation, I'd expect CI's from the 60 ton sample to be approximately $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\approx 40\%$ smaller than the 20 ton sample.

Whether this is beneficial depends on the underlying variability of the process and your performance targets. You are trying to remove a high percentage of material that only composes 5% of your total sample, so I'd expect that small absolute differences will make a big difference in the removal fractions.

As a baseline check, take the assumed variability of removal per ton (say, $\pm 10\%$) and multiply by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{20}} \approx 25\%$. This is a rough gauge of the reduction in variability you're getting by using 20 tons. Now, multiply this by 3 and subtract it from your target percentages. These numbers are rough estimates of the lowest removal fractions that would *not* be rejected by a statistical test.

For example, if your total variability of iron removal is $\pm 10\%$ for a ton of treated ash, then, your 20 ton test will reduce this to approximately $\pm 2.5\%$, which means that even if your process removes 90% of ferrous material, you would only be able to conclude that the removal rate is *at least* $90\%-2.5\% \times 3 = 82.5\%$.

This is just an example, but it illustrates that your question requires knowing something about the expected variability of your process *given* it is operating correctly.